# Does Gtk# have an Enum for key values?

Tags: c#, gtk, gtk#

In my code, I have messy things like

```
// Enter key
if (args.Event.KeyValue == 65293)
    ...
```

Is there any Enum I can use for this, instead of hard-coding the values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes: [Gdk.Key](http://go-mono.com/docs/index.aspx?tlink=24@ecma:274%23Key/) in the gdk-sharp.dll assembly.

```
if (args.Event.KeyValue == Gdk.Key.Return) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

args.Event.Key is the same thing, but as a Gdk.Key enum instead of a uint, so if you were to Console.WriteLine it, you'd get the nice name instead of the uint value.